# What's the purpose of is_uploaded_file()?

Tags: php

Docs say:

> Returns TRUE if the file named by filename was uploaded via HTTP POST

How could `$_FILES['blah']['tmp_name']` possibly not be the result of a POST upload? PHP created this filename.

> This is useful to help ensure that a malicious user hasn't tried to
>   trick the script into working on files upon which it should not be
>   working--for instance, /etc/passwd.

I understand that I should carefully check the file contents and size. But how could an attacker control whatsoever the **temp filename** of the uploaded file?

Or does `is_uploaded_file()` do some other checks?

Thanks for shedding some light.

Comment: Correction: `is_uploaded_file()` not `is_upload_file()`.

Comment: It's also redundant since `move_uploaded_file()` does the very same check again.

Comment: @mario: No, that's not a redundancy at all, because you are not forced to call one with the other; you may use them in isolation.

Comment: well if you managed to set the $_FILES array yourself it returns false, making it difficult to fake a request by just setting the superglobals, which can make it hard to debug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you can pass *any* string to `is_uploaded_file`.

Sure, if you pass it something straight out of `$_FILES` then yes of course it'll always return `true`, but if you form the argument yourself then it may not.

Answer (score 31):

In its current form, `is_uploaded_file` checks that file uploads are enabled (otherwise it cannot possibly be an uploaded file) and that the provided filename has in fact been generated by PHP (I know this from looking at the source).

This is not really helpful, since if there was no problem during the upload then

```
is_uploaded_file($_FILES['blah']['tmp_name'])
```

would always return `true`.

However, consider that `$_FILES` has "only" been available since PHP 4.1.0, while `is_uploaded_file` appeared first with PHP 4.0.3. The conclusion that seems logical here is that *it was kind of hard to get uploaded file handling working securely before the `$_FILES` superglobal was made available*. If nothing else, non-superglobals can be injected into, and very easily so with `register_globals` enabled -- which used to be another sore point with the security of PHP.

If one is writing code today and using `$_FILES` like one is supposed to, then I 'd say `is_uploaded_file` in its current implementation is "useless" because there's no attack vector that can trick you into processing a "bad" file.

However, there's also another way of looking at things: `is_uploaded_file` is guaranteed to work correctly now and in the future, for as long as it's available, regardless of what the mechanics of uploading files and making them available to the programmer are. Maybe *right now* it does not provide anything concrete, but it's an abstraction over the concept of "secure file upload" that comes with a guarantee. I would think that there is no such guarantee for `$_FILES` (again, even though I 'd consider it a regression if the current status quo changes "for the worse").