# How does is_uploaded_file() add security?

Tags: php, security

I understand it as the function works against the

```
$_FILES['nn']['tmp_name']
```

This tmp_name is created by php at server and cannot (from my understanding) be manipulated by the client. In what sense does the function is_uploaded_file() add security?

SOURCE CODE:

```
/* {{{ proto bool is_uploaded_file(string path)
   Check if file was created by rfc1867 upload */
PHP_FUNCTION(is_uploaded_file)
{
    char *path;
    size_t path_len;

    if (!SG(rfc1867_uploaded_files)) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1, 1)
        Z_PARAM_STRING(path, path_len)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();

    if (zend_hash_str_exists(SG(rfc1867_uploaded_files), path, path_len)) {
        RETURN_TRUE;
    } else {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean outside of the [description provided in the manual](http://php.net/is_uploaded_file)?

Comment: @mistermartin Yes. Without tampering the actual php-script how could a remote client succeed in (from the manual): "trick the script into working on files upon which it should not be working--for instance, /etc/passwd"

Comment: Ok. I think I get it. The hacker can try to send a file containing an absolute path, such as "/etc/password". Browsers doesn't allow it but a hacker can manipulate a request, and with bad security on www-user, php could overwrite the file by looking at the absolute path and not understanding it's a path, not a filename. This should probably be corrected in php itself.

Comment: I'm not able to interpet the source code. Thankful for any clarification.

Answer (score 5):

This is the best information I could find...

According to the book Essential PHP Security by Chris Shiflett:

> If your code uses tmp_name without verifying that it is in fact the uploaded file (and not something like /etc/passwd), **a theoretical risk exists**. I refer to this as a theoretical risk because **there is no known exploit that allows an attacker to modify tmp_name**. However, don't let the lack of an exploit dissuade you from implementing some simple safeguards.

However, keep in mind that this was published Oct 20, 2005. I am not aware of any exploits that have since surfaced, or what the details surrounding the "theoretical" exploit are. He also talks about it [here](http://shiflett.org/articles/file-uploads).

There is a similar question on [security stack exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134397/exploitation-of-missing-is-uploaded-file-check) for further reference.

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261879/whats-the-purpose-of-is-uploaded-file , Jon points out the function as useless. I'm still curious if the function looks at the 'name', not only the 'tmp_name', but  browsing php source code is outside of my comfort-zone.

Comment: @user247245 the manual states: "For proper working, the function `is_uploaded_file()` needs an argument like `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`, - the name of the uploaded file on the client's machine `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` does not work".

Answer (score 1):

This is really mostly a sanity check for *you*, the programmer. There's nothing really any user ("hacker") could do that would make `tmp_name` refer to anything but the just uploaded file. However, in your code you may be passing file names around in complex ways; to avoid *programming mistakes* in such scenarios, `is_uploaded_file` gives you a tool to check whether you're really working with a file which was just uploaded, or whether you're trying to work with some other file. In the latter case, if your code mistakenly [under certain circumstances] works with *any* file instead of just uploaded files, an attacker *may* be able to exploit that mistake and gain access to files they shouldn't.